# Can't Edit Quick Explode

Tags: animation, particles, physics, dopesheet, timeline

I used the preset Quick Explode (Is it a preset?), and after a while, I wanted to change it so Quick Explode happened later on in the animation so I could animate before it (like you would on the dope sheet), but I couldn't find out how to. If anybody could help that would be AWESOME!
(P.S. I'm using cell fracture if that makes a difference)
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Quick explode adds both an [Explode Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/simulate/explode.html#explode-modifier) and [Particle System](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/index.html#emitter) to the active object. By default, the particle system will start and end on frame 1, causing the explosion to occur instantly.

To change this, go to [particle system settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/emission.html#options) and change the start and end frames to the desired frame.

[image]